# Any shorthand for comparision to null or required value?

Tags: c#, shorthand

Is there any clever shorthand in C# to this:

```
list.Where(x=> x.a.b == null || x.a.b == desiredIntValue)
```

Comment: `list.Where(x=> x.a.b ?? desiredIntValue == desiredIntValue)` if it's a shorthand at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In later C# versions you can use pattern matching with [logical patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#logical-patterns), specifically `or` in this case (assuming list is `IEnumerable<>` since the newer language features usually are not supported by expression trees) and constants:

```
const int desiredIntValue = 1;
list.Where(x=> x.a.b is null or desiredIntValue)
```

For non-constant values you can do something like:

```
list.Where(x => (x.a.b ?? desiredIntValue) == desiredIntValue);
```

Or for nullable value types

```
list.Where(x => x.a.b.GetValueOrDefault(desiredValue) == desiredValue);
```

But not sure if it can be considered as shorthand.

Comment: This is very pretty, but it requires `desiredIntValue` to be constant, and `desiredIntValue` is method param.

Comment: @Yoda updated post a bit.